# Infinite Series Question, difference between infinities

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation, infinity

Was just thinking about infinite series, what is wrong with the below?
$$s_1=\lim _{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}i =\infty $$
$$s_2=\lim _{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n i =\infty $$
$$\therefore \ s_1=s_2$$

Fixed the formula, I am not sure if this is wrong but every element of $s_2$ is larger than the corresponding element of $s_1$ (apart from i=1), is this just an oddity of infinity?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I realized I used n instead of i,. Is this still true? It just does not seem intuitive, although that may just be an oddity related to infinities.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115743/an-algebra-of-integrals/342651#342651

Answer (score 3):

The two series that you write diverges, so there is no real number that these sums approach as you take the limit. Sometimes one uses the symbol $\infty$ to denote the value of these sums, and in this sense, the two sums "converges" to the same limit -infinity. In my opinion, this is meaningless since this series diverges.

The example that you gave is good to see the differences between the infinities. The two sums have very different "**rates of divergence**". To see this, consider the partial sums
\begin{align}
a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k} \; , \\[6pt]
b_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k \; .
\end{align}
The sum of the first $n$ positive natural number is well known to give
$$ b_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \; . $$
Using the integral test, we can see that the sum of the Harmonic numbers is in the limit
$$ \ln n  = \int_1^{n} \frac{1}{k} dk \; \leq a_n \leq  \; 1 +  \int_1^{n} \frac{1}{k} dk = 1 + \ln n \; . $$

Thus, for large $n$ the partial sums behave like
\begin{align}
a_n  \; &\sim \; \ln n \; , \\
b_n \;&  \sim \; \frac{1}{2} \, n^2 \; , 
\end{align}
which is enough to see that the two series diverge. However, more importantly, we can see that the Harmonic series diverges very slowly in a logarithmic way were as the sum of the natural number diverges quadratically.

---

To answer the question, there is nothing wrong with it,  it is just notation. I just wanted to explain that you are right when you compare one partial sum with the other and they have grown very differently. For finite $n$ we can easily see that $a_n < b_n$ (and even $ \text{Exp} \, a_n < b_n$). However, when you sum over infinite number $n\in \mathbb{N}$ the two sums goes to infinity. After you sum the information on the rate of grown of the function is lost and there is no meaning in "$\infty < \infty$", both diverges (are $\infty$).